# Differences between Nest website and Firebase API

Tags: node.js, nest-api

My program is using the Firebase API and successfully getting data and changes back.

If you compare the data returned from the Firebase API and the nest website (Rest API) it looks like the Firebase data is rounded to the nearest integer (temps) or the nearest 5% for humidity.

Is this expected behavior? Why would the REST API have more exact numbers when Firebase is the preferred access method? How can I get the most exact data from Firebase.

Firebase data
[image: Data from Firebase API]

Rest API data
[image]

Comment: There should be no difference in the values. Is this on a real or simulated device?

Comment: @urman This is on a real device.  I believe know what might cause the difference.  I'm using the developer firebase API on the console output, while using API calls meant for home.nest.com on the excel sheet.  The API calls code comes from https://gist.github.com/beezly/9b2de3749d687fdbff3f

Comment: Ok thats what it looks like to me as well. I updated the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the unofficial API for the calls that are updating your spreadsheet. The unofficial API has no support of guaranteed accuracy.

As a side note use of the unofficial api is also very insecure. Never put your user credentials into anywhere other than a Nest owned domain.